# Removing EventListener isn't working - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks usernames. The username is called to localstorage when the Enter-key is pressed, and after that, I want the eventListener to stop. For some reason it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why!

```
var checkUserName = function(event) {

    let key = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (key === 13) {
        if (this.usernameInput.value.length <= 0) {
            throw new Error("Username to short!")
        } else if (/\s/g.test(this.usernameInput.value)) {
            throw new Error("No white spaces, please!")
        } else if (this.usernameInput.value.length > 30) {
            throw new Error("Username to long!")
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("username", JSON.stringify(this.usernameInput.value));
            this.usernameInput.value = "";
        }
    }
}.bind(this);

window.addEventListener("keypress", initiate => checkUserName(event));
window.removeEventListener("keypress", initiate => checkUserName(event));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `removeEventListener` needs to be *the function you want to remove*.

You are passing it a **new function** that does the same thing as the function you want to remove.

This should do the job:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkUserName);
window.removeEventListener("keypress", checkUserName);
```

Comment: also you fixed op's code because in the original `event` would be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `()=>{}` creates a new function. So you're passing two different anonymous functions created by double arrow syntax to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, while they should be the same. You can fix like that:

```
const fn =  event => checkUserName(event);
window.addEventListener("keypress", fn );
window.removeEventListener("keypress", fn);
```

But since the outer function does the same as inner function, you can skip it:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkUserName);
window.removeEventListener("keypress", checkUserName);
```

Comment: replacing `var` with `const` would be a good idea considering ES6 syntax